# sfml - graphic not showing once i change the context setting

Tags: opengl, c++, sfml

I am trying out `sfml` and want to draw simple 2D graphic on top of 3D object.

```
sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 24;
settings.majorVersion = 4;
settings.minorVersion = 1;//opengl v4.1
settings.attributeFlags =  sf::ContextSettings::Core;

sf::RenderWindow window( sf::VideoMode(1200,800),"sfml", sf::Style::Default, settings);

sf::CircleShape qs;
qs.setRadius(400);
qs.setPosition(400,400);

while(window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event evnt;
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt)) {
            switch (evnt.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

        window.draw(qs);

        window.display();
    }
```

the `sf::ContextSettings` is set so that I can use `openGL` to draw 3D graphic. but with this settings, my `qs` not showing in the window. if I comment out the `settings.majorVersion = 4;` and `settings.minorVersion = 1;`, then it appear.

I am rather new and not sure how it works.

1. Is this possible to be resolved?
2. Is it correct to think that I want to use `sfml` for interface graphic and `OpenGL` for 3D? How do people normally do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*I apologize if [my answer in relation to this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43302572/2470818)
didn't properly explain the cause and effect of this.*</sup>

The problem is that the SFML graphics module relies on some legacy OpenGL functionality. This means that if you create a (>= 3.2) core context then that functionality isn't available.

Thus you must specify that you need a backwards compatible context, which is done by setting:

```
settings.attributeFlags = sf::ContextSettings::Default;
```

Here's an excerpt from the [SFML 2.4.2 documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/structsf_1_1ContextSettings.php).

> When requesting a context with a version greater or equal to 3.2, you have the option of specifying whether the context should follow the core or compatibility profile of all newer (>= 3.2) OpenGL specifications. For versions 3.0 and 3.1 there is only the core profile. By default a compatibility context is created. You only need to specify the core flag if you want a core profile context to use with your own OpenGL rendering. **Warning: The graphics module will not function if you request a core profile context. Make sure the attributes are set to Default if you want to use the graphics module.**

Note that when it comes to OS X there's another condition as well.

> Apple only supports choosing between either a legacy context (OpenGL 2.1) or a core context (OpenGL version depends on the operating system version but is at least 3.2). Compatibility contexts are not supported. Further information is available on the [OpenGL Capabilities Tables](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/index.html) page. OS X also currently does not support debug contexts.

Comment: Seems like learning `OpenGL` with `OS X` is not a good options.